# How to make retrofit query parameter request without key name

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using the google auto complete web service. I want to call the

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&strictbounds&key=YOUR_API_KEY

But **strictbounds** parameter don't have the parameter name. I have created the retrofit request but not able to add strictbounds parameter

```
  @GET("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
    Call<PlaceSearchResult> searchPlaceByName(@Query("input") String input, @Query("location") String location
            , @Query("radius") String radius, @Query("key") String key);
```

How to add the parameter without key?

Comment: you have to pass this query in map

Comment: you forgot type query in your retrofit request

Comment: I try with map also but in the map the key I am entering is coming in the url.  the strictbounds is without any key

Comment: have you try this way  @GET("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?strictbounds")

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this:

```
@GET("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?strictbounds")
Call<PlaceSearchResult> searchPlaceByName(@Query("input") String input, @Query("location") String location
            , @Query("radius") String radius, @Query("key") String key);
```